# Count number of occurrences of words in list of list

Tags: python, nltk

I have the a dataset of aprox 5.000 different words and 5000 lines:

Example of 2 lines

```
data = [["I", "am", "John"], ["Where", "is", "John","?"]]
```

And what I want to do is count how many different words I have of each.

```
result = {"I": 1, "am": 1, "John": 2, "Where":1, ...}
```

But have no idea how to do it efficiently

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is there's a lot of convenience tools in in python standard library.

```py
import itertools
from collections import Counter

data = [["I", "am", "John"], ["Where", "is", "John", "?"]]
result = Counter(itertools.chain(*data))
# result: Counter({'John': 2, 'I': 1, 'am': 1, 'Where': 1, 'is': 1, '?': 1})
```

The asterisk (`*data`) is a syntax for unpacking iterable item to the form of arguments,right I'm not good to explain it by text. Let's see for example:

```py
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
print(*data)
print(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
```

The 2nd line and 3rd line is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension as such

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([word for sentence in data for word in sentence])
# or even
Counter(word for sentence in data for word in sentence)
# so you don't create the list containing every word
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a high level algorithm. Let me know if you want the actual code.

1. Create a dictionary called `counts`.
2. Iterate over `data`.
3. For each element in `data`, iterate over each string.
4. For each string, check if that word is in `counts`. If it is, increment the count. Otherwise, set `counts[word]=1`.
5. At the end, `counts` will have what you're looking for.

This takes `O(n)` time as you only visit each word once, so it's the most efficient you can perform this task.